# Do not debug or run in jvm,can you tell me what's the output?

Tags: java, jvm

```
package Test;

public class A {

    public A() {
        System.out.println("Enter construct A...");
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Enter A's init...");
    }

}

package Test;

public class B extends A {

    int i = 0; 
    int j;

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Enter B's init...");
        i = 100;
        j = 100;
    }

    public void printAll(){
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(j);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.printAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is that something you have to do in class?

Comment: This site is not a classroom. Do you have any question or you don't understand something about this code ?

Comment: hey , this is not the paper examination , why cannot run the code?

Comment: please see the http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask about what kind of questions are appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, new B gets first an A get created, first instance fields, then calling B's init() which sets i and j to 100. Then the B gets created, which initializes the i to 0.

```
Enter construct A...
Enter B's init...
0
100
```

Comment: Guess it's because the constructor is run before the non-static fields are initialized.

Comment: why does it print 100 for i instead of 0? By the time printall is called the constructor should've finished

Comment: Great answer,It's very interesting to see the strange behavior of JVM.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose:

```
Enter construct A...
Enter B's init...
100
100
```

Because the A constructor has to be called bevore B can be constructed
and as the class you're instatiating is from type B, the init of B is called (there is no super.init() call so the init method of class B hides the one from the super class)

Comment: Akku is right if you run the code by yourself.